# Do parameters from function change memory usage or speed usage in Js

Tags: javascript, optimization, memory-management

I know this is premature optimization but I am just curious to know how long does it do solve this
(Take note, I know it not much difference only but what about in large game loops where the variables can be reused?)

```
function testone(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3)
{
     return parameter1 * parameter2 * parameter3;
}
console.log("" + testone(50,50,50));
```

VS

```
var
parameter1 = 50,
parameter2 = 50,
parameter3 = 50,
result = 0;

function testtwo()
{
   result = parameter1 * parameter2 * parameter3;
}

testtwo();
console.log("" + result);
```

I just do not know how to benchmark so if I knew I would do it myself but if this is a really bad question please do not -rep me, just tell me and I'll remove the question

Answer (score 0):

Functions get optimized by the JIT compiler in your browser. The latter approach requires a more roundabout way to access the variables.

http://jsperf.com/params-vs-lexical-scope

The above JSPerf test shows that this is indeed the case. Even if the second example was better performance-wise, it would be significantly harder to maintain and wouldn't be worth whatever minor benefit you'd receive from it.